# Assigning variable workbook name with Inputbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to assign an input box string to a workbook name in order to manipulate data from one sheet to the next. For example, when I generate a report it is assigned a temporary file name "tmp1" "tmp2" etc. I would like to use another excel sheet as a program which will run a macro in order to sort, copy, etc. the newly generated file, with only having to enter the name of the temporary file "tmp1" etc.

I am able to run the macro that I need and am familiar with the 'With' statements that will allow me to do so. my issue is when I run the following code:

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim X As String
X = InputBox("Set work book name")
Set wb = Workbooks(X)

With Workbooks(x)
.'code is entered here'
End with
End sub
```

I run into an object error. It seems I am incorrectly referencing the new file. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't look wrong, is the workbook opened in the same application ? is it correctly created with the input name ? Or is it a sheet ? Moreover, in your code, you're setting up a `wb` so use it in the `with` statement imo.

Comment: If you are attempting to create a new workbook and assign a specific name to it, then use `Workbooks.Add` to create it and then `Save` it with the specified name.

Comment: Hi @JeanRostan, it looks fine to me as well. Even when I save the temporary file and give it a proper name in excel format I run into the same issue. I receive a run-time error '9' subscript out of range and line containing

    "set wb = Workbooks(x)"

flags yellow

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to create a new temporary workbook and assign a filename to it then try:

```
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim X As String
    X = InputBox("Set work book name")
    Workbooks.Add

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\" & X & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    With ActiveWorkbook
        'code is entered here'
    End With
End Sub
```

*(Of course, you would use your own folder-name and your file-type)*

**EDIT#1:**
specifically in your code, try replacing:

```
With Workbooks(x)
```

with:

```
With Workbooks(x & ".xlsx")
```

or

```
With Workbooks(x & ".xlsm")
```

**EDIT#2:**

If you are save as text, then try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\" & x & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

and refer like:

```
With Workbooks(x & ".txt")
```

Comment: Hi Gary, unfortunately this is not the issue. The temporary workbook has already been opened at this point. What I would like to do is have a separate sheet already open in which executes the macro. I use the name of the tmp file and in my input box in order for my code to sort and tally certain items with in it. Similar to that of having input the code straight into the temporary sheet. It seems trivial but I run dozens of these reports a day and this would save a lot of time.

Comment: Is my **EDIT#1** of any value??

Comment: Yes somewhat! So it is now working for files saved as excel files. However it is not working for the temporary excel files. This isn't a huge issue - if you're curious the files are defaulted to save as "text (tab delimited)" files. I assume this is the issue as the extension is what was throwing me off for the files saved as excel files. Is there an extension that I could use which would allow me to access the text files?

Comment: @RileySittler  See my **EDIT#2**