# Assign workbook names with Inputboxes, creating dims

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will initially receive the 2 workbook names (file names) through inputboxes, will create a `dim` for each workbook, and then copy specific cells from workbook1 to workbook2.

I have the copying between sheets down okay, but I need help with the inputboxes relating to the dims.

I have pulled some code from elsewhere and edited it as far as I know for my needs, but I cant seem to make it work. 
[Assigning variable workbook name with Inputbox VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907940/assigning-variable-workbook-name-with-inputbox-vba)

I am pretty new to dim's so I am sure I am just missing something there.

```
Sub copytoworking()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim X As String
X = InputBox("What is this Working workbook's name?")
Set wb = Workbooks(X)
With Workbooks(X & ".xlsx")

Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Y As String
Y = InputBox("What is the source data workbook's name?")
Set wb2 = Workbooks(Y)
With Workbooks(Y & ".xlsx")

'copying between sheets code is here

End With
End With
End Sub
```

Right now I am getting an error '9' on `Set wb = Workbooks(X)`.

Comment: Instead of getting the workbook name from an InputBox, is [`GetOpenFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) an option? I.e. do the workbooks have to be already open?

Comment: `Set wb = Workbooks(X  & ".xlsx")` assuming the user only enters the name without an extension and all workbook are xlsx format.

Comment: FYI you cannot use nested `With` blocks to refer to *both* workbooks - only the innermost `With` will be active for your "copying between sheets" code

Answer (score 0):

In the InputBox are you entering a value such as -

```
 "C:\Users\HP\Documents\EbayPrice"
```

The following isn't perfect but it should lead you in the right direction. You probably need to put some validations in place to avoid opening a non Excel file and in case you click Cancel instead of selecting a file.

```
 Dim wb, wb2, wbname, wb2name As String
    wb = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    wb2 = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=wb
    wbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=wb2
    wb2name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Windows(wbname).Activate
    Windows(wb2name).Activate
```

Comment: The goal is for the inputbox to just receive the file name (no .xlsx), I do not want to have to go searching for the file each time. So if we are copying from filename Original.xlsx, the inputbox should just receive "Original"